# Get the footer from excel document

Tags: c#, excel

How can I get the footer of an Excel document with C#? Below is the code I used to retrieve the footer.

```
string sFooterExcel = string.Empty;
xlsApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlsWorkbook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(sPath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
 int i = xlsWorkbook.Worksheets.Count;
 foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in xlsWorkbook.Worksheets)
 {
  sFooterExcel = sheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter;
            sFooterExcel += sFooterExcel + sheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter;
            sFooterExcel += sFooterExcel + sheet.PageSetup.RightFooter;
        }
        return sFooterExcel;
    }
```

But I am getting the font data like:

```
"&"Trebuchet MS,Bold"&10 Confidential&"Trebuchet MS,Bold"&10 Confidential"
```

I want only **'Confidential'** as my footer. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think that you need to eliminate Excel format codes from Left/Center/RightFooter strings manually. You can find these codes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822794.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manually strip the formatting. You can find the formatting codes at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff822794(v=office.15).aspx.

For example a regex can strip it:

```
private static string TrimFormatting(string headerOrFooter)
{
    return Regex.Replace(headerOrFooter, "&L|&C|&R|&E|&X|&Y|&B|&I|&U|&S|&\"[^\"]+\"|&(\\d\\d|\\d)|&K[0-9a-fA-F]{6}|&K\\d\\d[\\+\\-]\\d\\d\\d", string.Empty);
}
```

Then you can use this method to get footer's text

```
sFooterExcel = TrimFormatting(sheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter);
sFooterExcel += TrimFormatting(sheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter);
sFooterExcel += TrimFormatting(sheet.PageSetup.RightFooter);
```

Comment: Thank you... Can you tell me what is LeftFooter, CenterFooter, RightFooter? Because i am getting 'Confidential' in both Centerfooter and RightFooter.

Comment: These are parts of the footer. They are shown like [here](http://i.imgur.com/NffggO3.png) in Excel.